# UITabbar slides down bug

Tags: ios, uitabbar

In some cases I have such bug (look at the screen). I don't know how to repeat it, but it happens. As you can see, tabbar change height and titles are hidden. How can fix it?

[image]

Comment: @bobby tabbar change height and titles are hidden

Comment: You are missing 40px on retina display. Which is the height of the status bar. There is your starting point.

Comment: @Desdenova, ok, but how it can happens?